# How do I get this dropdown to be on top of the other elements

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu, that looks like this:

```
<ul id="secondary-nav" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">boeketten</a>
        <ul>
            <li>7 rododendrons</li>
            <li>7 rozen</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">bloemstukken</a></li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">planten</a></li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">bruidsruikers</a></li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">kerkdecoratie</a></li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">evenementen</a></li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">rouwwerk</a></li>
    <span>∼</span>
    <li><a href="#">rocabo potten</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the css I use to style it:

```
ul#secondary-nav {
    z-index: 9999;
}

ul#secondary-nav li, ul#secondary-nav > span {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}

ul#secondary-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: red;
}

ul#secondary-nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}

ul#secondary-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But it falls under the rest of the content, like this:

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

How can I get it to be on top of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you defined a `z-index` for your main `ul` but it seems to be in static position (so `z-index` has no effect) : try with

```
ul#secondary-nav {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Depending on your markup, you may also need to apply position: relative; to the container of your UL too (IE issues)