# Keep the drop down menu on top of other elements

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu to change the language but when the list got longer and the menu now is behind the other element.

I don't really get what is need to be change or what CSS I have to apply to get the dropdown stay on top of the other elements so that they can still see the list and select them.

[image]

I'm trying to get most of the CSS that applied to the element, but they are "LESS"

These are part of them

```
li.lang-picker:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.ui-append.ui-select {
  background-color: white;
}
#lang-picker {
  margin: -7px 15px 0 -18px;
  border-color: transparent;
}
#lang-picker:hover {
  border-color: #CCC;
}
#lang-picker ul {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
#lang-picker ul li {
  display: block;
}
#lang-picker .ui-select-menu {
  width: auto;
  border-color: #CCC;
}
#lang-picker .ui-select-menu ul {
  width: auto;
}
#lang-picker .ui-selected::before {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#lang-picker .ui-smedium {
  width: auto;
}
#lang-picker > .icon {
  background: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#lang-picker > .icon:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #555;
}
/*********************************************************
* Filter
*/
.gallery-header .header {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.gallery-header .header h1,
.gallery-header .header p {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -0.25px;
}
.gallery-header .header h1 {
  font-size: 2.4em;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #3fb58e;
}
.gallery-header .header p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #555555;
}
.gallery-header .header p a {
  color: #20abdc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.gallery-header .header p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #4abce5;
}
#tools h1 {
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.filter {
  position: relative;
  background: #3fb58e;
  float: right;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.filter label {
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.filter #search-filter {
  border-color: #38a27f;
}
.filter #search-filter:hover {
  border-color: #2b7c61;
}
.filter #search-filter .icon {
  background: #328f70;
}
.filter #search-filter .ui-select-menu {
  border-color: #3fb58e;
}
.filter:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #3fb58e;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Most likely you need to change the z-index. Please post your HTML and CSS here.

Comment: I'm going to get the CSS and HTML that I can and update them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this dropdown to be on top of the other elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526631/how-do-i-get-this-dropdown-to-be-on-top-of-the-other-elements)

Answer (score 7):

You can use 'z-index' property together with 'position' property.
In order 'z-index' to work, position should be set to 'relative'.

Comment: It does work @mikeGordo except is not the way it suppose to be I guess https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/n5v3bx9nnjkdpzf/_dv2hfnv.png

Comment: @Ali not sure what am I looking at. How should it be?

Comment: Sorry is this a better picture? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/n5v3bx9nnjkdpzf/u-oyrnu9.png it shouldn't go way off the menu itself.

Comment: @Ali oh i see. your css listing for those elements would help to understand what exactly is going on here :)

Comment: I don't know how to get all those up in the question but this is the file in the github page https://github.com/mozilla/login.webmaker.org/blob/master/app/http/public/css/account.less

Answer (score 3):

Give z-index:100 or more try giving more.

```
div.ui-select-menu
{
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: You're making assumptions here. You don't know if a z-index of 100 is enough to accomplish what the OP needs, but more importantly, a z-index rule alone won't do anything unless the element has been positioned.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the `position` attribute to something that is not `static`. If there are only `static`(the default value) elements in the page, then setting `position: relative;` will do. However if there are elements whose `position` isn't `static` then you need to set the `z-index` attribute to a value higher than the other elements' `z-index`.